# How to Convert Interpolated Map to Excel using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, excel

I have interpolated some SO2 data using IDW and have calculated means on county level using Zonal Statistics. I would like to convert this data now into an excel file. I already got the hint, that I should use the Conversion Tool and Table to Excel. However, I can only convert the two tables I have imported from shape files. That is the map with the counties and the data with SO2 values and measuring stations. Do I have to convert the values I obtained from Zonal Statistics?

I hope I was able to describe my problem sufficiently.

I am using ArcMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "zonal statistics as table" and not "zonal statistics" if you want a table as output. The resulting table will be visible when you set your table of content to "[listing by source](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000006000000)". Then you can use Table to Excel.

Comment: Thanks, it works a lot better with using zonal statistics as table!

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap, you can [export any table of attribute data to a separate table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000001t000000). Right-click on the feature of interest (your Zonal Statistics output, in this case), and select "Open Attribute Table." [In the table view](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000038000000), click the Table Options button (top left-most button) and find "Export..." and then you'll be able to export just the table of data.

Once you export the table to "text" (actually a CSV file, but it will have a .txt extension), it is then very straightforward to import into Excel.